# Grails 2.2.5, Shiro plugin - non-standard port causing problems

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, shiro

I'm having great difficulty working out what's going on with a Grails 2.2.5 application which uses the Shiro plugin (v.1.2.1). This is on a system which has been working fine for a couple of years. It sits behind an nginx remote proxy server, which has hitherto been listening on ports 80/443. We've just moved the test rig, and it now shares a server with an Apache installation which has those ports, so we have nginx listening on ports 8070 for http and 8443 for https. It's largely working, but there are some puzzling problems with redirects when a user is not authenticated, and these problems seem to be coming from Shiro (although I'm having difficulty being certain).

Basically what's happening is that when an unauthenticated user goes to 'https://myapp.com:8443/admin/', the Grails application is issuing a redirect which takes them to 'https://myapp.com:8443/auth/login?targetUri=%2F' - i.e., the context has been stripped out. It should be 'https://myapp.com:8443/admin/auth/login?targetUri=%2F', and is so on the live server, which uses the standard ports (80/443). In fact, when I look at the Location header in the response, what it's actually responding with is 'http://myapp.com:8070/auth/login?targetUri=%2F' (i.e., with the http port, which is no problem as nginx is handling SSL).

Because my code, in AuthController.groovy, doesn't actually get involved until it receives the /auth/login request, this problem doesn't seem to be coming from anywhere in my code, and must be coming from the Shiro plugin. But why would the non-standard port be causing this problem (stripping out the context)? And more importantly, what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have been wrongly ascribing blame to Shiro or the Shiro plug-in here. I have solved the problem, which seems to be caused by a quirk in Grails itself.

In version 1 of Grails, one had to set grails.serverURL correctly in Config.groovy in order for redirects to work properly, but with version 2 that was no longer necessary, and in fact this property was commented out in a newly created app.

However, whatever was done doesn't seem to play nicely with non-standard ports. If the server port is something like 8070 or 8443, as I was using the redirect is incorrectly formed.

I have resolved the issue by reinstating grails.serverURL and making sure it's configured correctly. Now redirects work as they should again.